# Bluetooth and Wi-Fi not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, bluetooth

I'm working on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine, and I would like to use my bluetooth headphones. The card is a **Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter**, can't find a proper driver to install to make it work.

This is the output of `inxi -Fxz`:

```
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: d000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: enp3s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: rtl8821ce port: c000 bus-ID: 04:00.0
           IF: wlp4s0 state: down mac: <filter>
```

This is the output of `rfkill list`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

And this is the output of `dmesg` that I think it's related to all of it:

```
[    2.482158] usb 1-13: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[    7.740358] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    7.740365] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    7.740367] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    7.740368] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    7.740373] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.350597] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
[    8.350599] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin
[    8.805573] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[   10.876381] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc20 tx timeout
[   18.872613] Bluetooth: hci0: download fw command failed (-110)
[   19.018324] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   19.018326] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   19.018328] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

I have no clue how to solve this issue, I already tried installing several drivers suggested in news related to this problem, but none of it worked. Any suggestion?